# The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3_API_30 has terminated for windows

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

As I have recently updated into arctic fox android studio version, I am not able to start my avd.
[image: Startup error message]

Tried many things such as downloaded hxam driver updated sdk but the is issue is still the same.
please anyone help be out with this

Comment: Probably the problem is related to the environment variable ANDROID_HOME which was pointing to a different SDK than the android studio's one. Make sure to have correct JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_SDK

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: I would start by going to the environment variable settings and removing all 3 that I've listed. Than, restart the computer and try to launch an emulator

Comment: No, it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the emulator in the AVD manager and reinstalled it. I also deleted the ANDROID_HOME environment variable and it worked again for me in Artic Fox

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be related to having a different directory for SDK , so add ANDROID_HOME in environmental variable with the value pointing to the directory containing the SDK