# Emulator process for AVD Pixel 3 API 30 has terminated

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-sdk-manager, avd-manager

How do I fix the problem, it comes whenever I try to run my Android studio

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The emulator process for AVD Pixel\_3\_API\_30 has terminated for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68789712/the-emulator-process-for-avd-pixel-3-api-30-has-terminated-for-windows)

Comment: On the action box, click the down arrow icon. Press wipe data. It's worked for me